# Aligning Polygons to Margins in Data Driven Pages

Tags: arcmap, polygon, data-driven-pages, alignment

I'm creating a data driven page of polygons (forest subcompartments) on a basemap in ArcMap 10.4.1. The scale required for outputted maps is predefined (1:5,000). Output is multi page pdfs.

Users of the outputted maps/pdfs will be required to add legends to the right hand side of the maps/pdfs (pasted jpg/bmp).

In Layout view is there a way to align the polygons so the western most portion of the polygon boundary is displayed near the left margin of the layout, i.e., keep the map pages from centering on the polygon?

Comment: Are all the output maps the same size? Do the sizes of the polygons vary a lot?

Comment: After you selected your page size in the Data Frame Properties Size and Position form choose a width for it that is less than the print/exported page size and offset that to leave a large white area to the right of the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

The essence of the data-driven mapping process is zooming to the centroid of the index features. So if you want to control how the map centers that feature, you have to change the input shapes. If you want to show an intersection near a cluster of buildings, then you might need to edit a building buffer feature so it includes the intersection. That makes sense for my stuff, but you need a different approach since you are holding the scale constant.

One approach would be to use the Feature to Point geoprocessing tool to create centroid points for your index polygons. Then move these points x amount of distance to the West. (My system is tied up exporting a mapbook so I can't test how to do this, but someone here will know if you can't figure it out.) Again, since you are holding the scale constant, the x amount can be the same distance and you can determine it using your map page. Then, you can use these points as your index feature for your data-driven map.